# Types of parameters 'err' and 'error' are incompatible. Type 'ExecException | null' is not assignable to type 'Error'

Tags: node.js, typescript

**Here is my program:**

```
import * as child_process from 'child_process'

let global_npm_modules = ''

const initial_command = 'npm ls -g --depth=0 --json'
const shell = 'powershell'
const callback = (err: Error, stdout: string | Buffer, stderr: string | Buffer) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error\n\n', err)
        return
    }

    console.log(stdout)
}

child_process.exec(initial_command, {shell: shell}, callback)
```

**And `tslint` is complaining about `callback` in the last line giving the error:**

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(err: Error, stdout: string | Buffer, stderr: string | Buffer) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(error: ExecException | null, stdout: string | Buffer, stderr: string | Buffer) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'err' and 'error' are incompatible.
    Type 'ExecException | null' is not assignable to type 'Error'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Error'.
const callback: (err: Error, stdout: string | Buffer, stderr: string | Buffer) => void
```

---

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here. I was going off the Node documentation here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

And I was just using the types provided in this section:

```
callback <Function> called with the output when process terminates.

error <Error>
stdout <string> | <Buffer>
stderr <string> | <Buffer>
```

---

**Here is my `tsconfig.json`:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

I also have `@types/node` installed.

**EDIT**

With Node, the documentation says this about `child_process.exec()`: *"If a callback function is provided, it is called with the arguments (error, stdout, stderr). On success, error will be null."*

But with TypeScript, the `Error` type is defined as

```
interface Error {
    stack?: string;
}
```

Should I just add `| null` to the possible type that the `error` parameter can be? Or is this a bug with the `@types/node` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the first argument of callback is defined as `ExecException | null` and `ExecException` extends `Error`. And since a callback function is provided by the programmer to the library and would be called by the library, it should cover all the possibilities of the arguments that might be passed to it.

Your `callback: (error: Error, /* code omitted */) => ChildProcess` can only handles, regarding to its type declaration, the case where `error` is of type `Error` and can not handle the case where `error` is null. So tsc is emitting a type error.

I can think of two solutions to this for now:

1. Add `| null` to the type declaration of `error`

```ts
    const callback = (err: Error | null, stdout: string | Buffer, stderr: string | Buffer) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There was an error\n\n', err)
            return
        }

        console.log(stdout)
    }
```

2. Infer the expected type of the callback from existing declaration and then declare the callback with that inferred type.

```ts
    type CallbackType = typeof child_process.exec extends (cmd: string, options: any, callback: infer P) => ChildProcess ? P : any 

    const callback: CallbackType  = (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There was an error\n\n', err)
            return
        }

        console.log(stdout)
    }
```

[Check it in online repl](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0A%20*%20mock%20interfaces%20to%20make%20ts%20happy%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Ainterface%20ChildProcess%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Buffer%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20BufferEncoding%20%7B%20%7D%20%0D%0Ainterface%20ExecOptions%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shell%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ExecException%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0A%20*%20copied%20from%20%40types%2Fnode%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20no%20%60options%60%20definitely%20means%20stdout%2Fstderr%20are%20%60string%60.%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20exec(command%3A%20string%2C%20callback%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20ExecException%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%2C%20stderr%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20ChildProcess%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60options%60%20with%20%60%22buffer%22%60%20or%20%60null%60%20for%20%60encoding%60%20means%20stdout%2Fstderr%20are%20definitely%20%60Buffer%60.%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20exec(command%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20%7B%20encoding%3A%20%22buffer%22%20%7C%20null%20%7D%20%26%20ExecOptions%2C%20callback%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20ExecException%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20Buffer%2C%20stderr%3A%20Buffer)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20ChildProcess%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60options%60%20with%20well%20known%20%60encoding%60%20means%20stdout%2Fstderr%20are%20definitely%20%60string%60.%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20exec(command%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20%7B%20encoding%3A%20BufferEncoding%20%7D%20%26%20ExecOptions%2C%20callback%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20ExecException%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%2C%20stderr%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20ChildProcess%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60options%60%20with%20an%20%60encoding%60%20whose%20type%20is%20%60string%60%20means%20stdout%2Fstderr%20could%20either%20be%20%60Buffer%60%20or%20%60string%60.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20There%20is%20no%20guarantee%20the%20%60encoding%60%20is%20unknown%20as%20%60string%60%20is%20a%20superset%20of%20%60BufferEncoding%60.%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20exec(command%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20%7B%20encoding%3A%20string%20%7D%20%26%20ExecOptions%2C%20callback%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20ExecException%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer%2C%20stderr%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20ChildProcess%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60options%60%20without%20an%20%60encoding%60%20means%20stdout%2Fstderr%20are%20definitely%20%60string%60.%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20exec(command%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20ExecOptions%2C%20callback%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20ExecException%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%2C%20stderr%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20ChildProcess%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20fallback%20if%20nothing%20else%20matches.%20Worst%20case%20is%20always%20%60string%20%7C%20Buffer%60.%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20exec(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20command%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20(%7B%20encoding%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7D%20%26%20ExecOptions)%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callback%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20ExecException%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer%2C%20stderr%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A)%3A%20ChildProcess%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20code%20from%20question%20%0D%0Aconst%20initial_command%20%3D%20'npm%20ls%20-g%20--depth%3D0%20--json'%0D%0Aconst%20shell%20%3D%20'powershell'%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20callback%20%3D%20(err%3A%20Error%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer%2C%20stderr%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('There%20was%20an%20error%5Cn%5Cn'%2C%20err)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(stdout)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexec(initial_command%2C%20%7B%20shell%20%7D%2C%20callback)%20%2F%2F%20type-error%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%201%0D%0A%2F%2F%20add%20%22%7C%20null%22%20to%20the%20type%20annotation%20of%20first%20argument%20to%20make%20it%20accord%20with%20the%20required%20one.%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20callback_sln1%20%3D%20(err%3A%20Error%20%7C%20null%2C%20stdout%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer%2C%20stderr%3A%20string%20%7C%20Buffer)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('There%20was%20an%20error%5Cn%5Cn'%2C%20err)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(stdout)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexec(initial_command%2C%20%7B%20shell%20%7D%2C%20callback_sln1)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%202%0D%0A%2F%2F%20using%20%5Btype%20inference%20in%20conditional%20types%5D%5B1%5D%2C%20we%20can%20%22extract%22%20the%20expected%20type%20of%20the%20third%20argument%20of%20the%20%60exec%60%20function.%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20CallbackType%20%3D%20typeof%20exec%20extends%20(cmd%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20any%2C%20callback%3A%20infer%20P)%20%3D%3E%20ChildProcess%20%3F%20P%20%3A%20any%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20callback_sln2%3A%20CallbackType%20%20%3D%20(err%2C%20stdout%2C%20stderr)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('There%20was%20an%20error%5Cn%5Cn'%2C%20err)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(stdout)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexec(initial_command%2C%20%7B%20shell%20%7D%2C%20callback_sln2)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B1%5D%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.typescriptlang.org%2Fdocs%2Fhandbook%2Fadvanced-types.html%23type-inference-in-conditional-types)

Comment: I think I prefer method 1 for now. Thank you for looking at the problem and responding.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this problem is to add

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false
}
```

to the `tsconfig.json`.

But hopefully, in the future, I can figure out a solution that doesn't require this.

**EDIT**

Or `| null` can be added as a type annotation for `err`. I opted to choose this more specific solution.